# how we calculate the divs count in html file using python?

Tags: python, selenium

I want the total no of `div`s present in html file.

I want the solution in python.

I have tried following code to find `div`s using class but now i want size of that `div`s.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import random

HTMLFile = open("/home/earth/sample.html", "r")
file = HTMLFile.read()
print(file)

S = BeautifulSoup(file, 'lxml')
Des = S.body
Attr_Tag = [e.name for e in Des.descendants if e.name is not None]
print(Attr_Tag)

mydivs = S.findAll('div',class_="col")
#mydivs=S.select('.col')

print(mydivs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the track.

`findAll` method return's a list so you can simply call the built-in `len` method to find out the size of the `list[div]`

Just change the last part to this;

```
mydivs = S.findAll('div',{'class': "col"})
print(len(mydivs))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using *Selenium* to count the number of `<div>` tags you can use the [*`len()`*](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_len.asp) function and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CLASS_NAME*:

  ```
  print(len(driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "div")))
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print(len(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div")))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print(len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div")))
  ```